# Setting up a Server with Dual Stack Lite

Tags: networking, router, ipv6

I have the following problem:

My ISP provides me with a shared IPv4 address and a universal IPv6 address (Dual Stack Lite).

I want to host a (game) server at my home but I've ran into a few problems. First of all, if I enable the ports in my router (Fritz!Box 7590), a private IPv4 address shows up:

[image: Pic]

So I've tried to reach my "public" IPv4 address (obviously from a friend's PC) with the IP from http://ipchicken.com, which results in a 100% packet loss.

So my questions are now:

~ How can I setup a server with IPv4? (What would be the best way to setup the server in this situation?)

~ Would it be a good idea to completely switch to IPv6 and force the clients to use IPv6 as well?

I'm fairly new to networking with IPv6 so if I've made any obvious mistakes please let me know.

Comment: Does the game support IPv6? There are services that offer "Dynamic DNS" which will route a subdomain to your IPv4 address. These typically require a client application on your network to regularly check for the current public IP and report it to the service. Have you looked into these?

Comment: With a DS-Lite connection you cannot run a server on IPv4. You can run it on IPv6 if all players also have IPv6.

Comment: You can't use IPv4 as a server at all. It must be IPv6.